# Document.getElement*** always returns empty inside an element bind block of a link function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

**My Directive:**

```
app.directive('someDirName', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            element.bind('click', function () {
                console.log('Hey, I am here!');
                var arr = angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('some-class-name'));
                console.log(arr);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**My test:**

```
var html = '<div class="some-class-name"/>' +
            '<div class="some-class-name"/>' +
        '<a id="link" some-dir-name>More</a>';

var element = $compile(html)(scope);
scope.$digest();
var link = angular.element(element[2]);
link.trigger('click');
```

Now, when I run this test, I can see that the line 'Hey I am here!' is printed, but the content of the array of objects with class name 'some-class-name' is empty!

The directive works fine when running in the app, it can find the elements and can do operations on it. But I can't seem to figure out how the array is empty ONLY during the test.

Note: I tried to get elements by id, class name..etc, all yield the same result.

Comment: The mere fact that you compiled your HTML does not make it part of the current document. Not in document == document.getElement(s)ByWhatever won’t find any of those elements.

Comment: So, how do you test this code?

Comment: Try angular.element('body').append(html), before you compile the html.